# Restkit: RKValueTransformer transformationBlock doesn't called

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Here is what I have:

in my JSON response I have an array of options:
`Options : ["red","green", "blue"]`

I want to convert it to an string: `options = @"red, green, blue";` (I have defined `options` property of menuComponent entity as 'NSString')

I have provided a customValueTransformer for that property, but transformationBlock doesn't get called.
does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
RKEntityMapping *menuComponentMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MenuComponent" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

menuComponentMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"menuComponentID"];
[menuComponentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                           @"ID":@"menuComponentID",
                                                           @"Name":@"name",
                                                           @"Description":@"descriptions",
                                                           @"Thumbnail":@"thumbnail"
                                                           }];
//every menu component have some options
RKAttributeMapping *optionsMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"Options" toKeyPath:@"options"];

//converting options to string
RKValueTransformer *arrayToStringTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
    // I don't know check what with what!
    return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]);
} transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, Class outputValueClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    // Validate the input and output

    // Perform the transformation
// iterating through options and append to a string

    return YES;
}];

//adding custom value transformer
optionsMapping.valueTransformer = arrayToStringTransformer;
//adding optionsMapping
[menuComponentMapping addPropertyMapping:optionsMapping];
[[RKValueTransformer defaultValueTransformer] insertValueTransformer:arrayToStringTransformer atIndex:0];

RKRelationshipMapping *menuComponentRelationShip = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"MenuComponents" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:menuComponentMapping];

//adding menucomponent children relationship to menuComponent
[menuComponentMapping addPropertyMapping:menuComponentRelationShip];

return menuComponentMapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code even comments this section as an issue:

```
// I don't know check what with what!
return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]]);
```

because you aren't trying to convert from an `NSNumber`, you're trying to convert from an `NSArray`. If the class types don't match then the transformer will not be used.

If that block isn't called, then the problem is with the transformer registration. That shouldn't happen when the transformer is provided directly to the mapping but you haven't shown how the mapping is then used...

Comment: I have a restaurantEntity which has relationship to menuComponentEntity. in my responseDescriptor I provide my restaurantMapping and a webApi url. restaurantManager loads all data whithout any issue. options `valueTransformerWithValidationBlock` called twice: first time destination is kind of NSString and sourceClass is kind of `NCSFString` and second time destinationClass is kind of NSNumber, source class is kind of `NSCFNumber` but but transformation class doesn't called. if for example add custom value transformer to another property like `name`, transform block gets called!

Comment: Turn on trace logging. What data type is set in the data model? And the managed object class was auto generated?